# C# iterate list for objects without some fields

Tags: c#

how can I iterate List<> of objects having only two of four fields?
Below code works so far but is there easier way to do that in C#?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var list = new List<Employee>
            {
                new Employee("A", 32, 5235.32, 2004, 3, 2),
                new Employee("B", 28, 1435.43, 2011, 11, 23),
                new Employee("C", 47, 3416.49, 1997, 5, 17),
                new Employee("D", 22),
                new Employee("E", 57)
            };
            list.ForEach(l => {
                if (l.Salary == 0) Console.WriteLine(" {0} {1}", l.Name, l.Age);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with `only two of four`?

Comment: @MichaelMairegger Clearly meant `only two or four fields`.

Comment: @DrewKennedy I do not understand what your question is

Comment: For example, I need to get Employee(string, int) not Employee(string , int, double , date).

Comment: You won't know what constructor was called to initialize an object after it's constructed, you'll need to rely on a side effect of that constructor to filter out items you don't want (e.g. `salary == 0`), or, better yet, don't put them in the same collection.

Comment: `Employee(string,int)` creates the *same* object as `Employee(string,int,double,whatever)`. They are not different objects.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just trying to filter items out of a collection - what you're doing works fine, but it's (arguably) more idiomatically written as:

```
foreach(var l in list.Where(x => x.Salary == 0))
{
    Console.WriteLine(" {0} {1}", l.Name, l.Age);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have the fields nullable.

```
class Employee
{
    // strings are nullable
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // this allows double values to be nullable (the ? at the end)
    public double? Salary { get; set; }
    public double? Double1 { get; set; }
}
```

Then when you query

```
var list = new List<Employee>();
// You can filter your list with Where() on if values have a value set or not
list.Where(x=> x.Salary.HasValue == false).ToList().ForEach( .. )
```

Information on using Nullable https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Reflection can help you get the only 2 first fields, since the only case where only 2 of your fields are filled is the case of Name and Age, then this would help you :

```
list.Where(l => l.GetType().GetProperties().Count(e => e.GetValue(e)!=null) == 2).ToList().ForEach(l => 
{
     Console.WriteLine(" {0} {1}", l.Name, l.Age);
});
```